# Scheduled notifications using Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

I want to schedule automatic push notifications trough `Firebase` for my Android App. I have already searched the documentation, but could not find a way to do this.

Comment: Do you want automatic push notification at a particular time?

Comment: Yeah i want to set a specific time. For example i want to push notifications on Monday at 06:00 am and 08:00 am.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

click on **Send Later** Button, then you can set the time for your `Notification`

Comment: Is it actually possible to change the time based on a var in my android app?
To be exact can i create an notification entry with lets say a timestamp from my android app?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through the Firebase Console. Go to the notifications tab and schedule a push notification.

If you want push notifications to be sent out periodically, you can set up a cron job in Firebase Functions.